# go-grpc Import "google/protobuf/struct.proto" was not found or had errors

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I'm using following command to generate proto code for golang:

```
protoc --go_out=../generated --go_opt=paths=source_relative \
    --go-grpc_out=../generated --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative \
    *.proto
```

I'm using in-built google/protobuf/struct.proto for unstructured data. However, I'm getting an error saying "google.protobuf.Struct" is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

`protoc` comprises `./bin` and `./include` directories.

The `./include` should include e.g. `google/protobuf/struct.proto`.

If you're correctly setting the `PATH` to `./protoc../bin`, `struct.proto` should be included in the compilation.

###### Example

`go.mod`:

```
module github.com/some/test

go 1.16

require google.golang.org/protobuf v1.26.0
```

`test.proto`:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package test;

import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";

option go_package = "github.com/some/test;test";

message SomeRequest {
  google.protobuf.Struct some_struct = 1;
}
```

Then:

```sh
protoc \
--go_out=. \
--go_opt=module=github.com/some/test  \
test.proto
```